# Taking turns with socket.io & node.js

Tags: jquery, node.js, socket.io

I am trying to make a turn based game, but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

I can't seem to disable a button for a particular user i.e. when it is not that persons turn they should not be allowed to do anything, in this case disabling draw and stand buttons. How do I make this turn based so other clients are disabled?

With my current code, the buttons are never disabled for any client and they can always player rather than on their turn.

server side

```
var express = require('express')
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

var users = [];
var index = 0;

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
socket.on('add-user', function(data) {
   users = [{
  'name': data,
  'socket': socket.id,
  'total': 0,
 }];
});

socket.on('game-start', function () { 
  if(users[index].socket === socket.id) {
    console.log(users[index].socket);
    console.log(socket.id);
    users[index].name.turn = true;
    socket.emit('enable-button');
    socket.on('draw', function() {
    ... game logic here ...
    });
    socket.on('stand-button', function() {
        // move to next player.
        if (users[index+1] != null) {
          index += 1;
          console.log(index);
        }
    });
   }
});

socket.on('disconnect', function() {
  for(var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    if(users[i].socket === socket.id) {
      io.emit('chat message', users[i].name + ' has rage quit!');
        break;
    }
  } 
});
});
```

client side

```
$('#stand').click(function() {
   socket.emit('stand-button');
   $('#draw').prop("disabled", true);
   $('#stand').prop("disabled", true);
});

socket.on('enable-button', function() {
  $('#draw').prop("disabled", false);
  $('#stand').prop("disabled", false);
});
```

Comment: Your logic in  `socket.on('add-user')` is wrong, you will always have one user. you should do `users.push([{'name':data,...'}])`

Comment: I do have multiple users, each has a different session.id. I did however, try users.push and that does not seem to work at all...but i guess they are all index 0? is that what you mean? Can you provide an example of users.push?

Comment: you can push it like:  `users.push({ 'name': data,'socket': socket.id,'total': 0});`. You do not need to push an array in it again, it will create a multi-dimentional array.

Comment: And how do you maintain `index` of `users[index]` ?

Comment: @Stamos. Thanks man, that helped some. Still having some trouble and that was definitely one of my problems.

Comment: @Chirag, this is one of the problems I think. I do not know a good approach for this. But basically, I have a if statement checking if the next index is null and if it is false it increments the global variable index. This happens when the stand button is clicked

Comment: @chirag you are correct my mistake, copy/paste... . @codingdraculasbrain you could emit `current-player` **only** and on each client you can handle buttons and other staff easier